# How to import variable columns into fixed columns in Excel 2007

Tags: text, ms-access-2007, excel-2007

I have a text file that has the variable columns.

I need to convert the variable columns to fixed columns in Excel 2007 (or Access Database 2007 - whichever works better? or however better anywhere!).

How do?

Thanks!
Holly

Comment: How are the columns separated in the text file??

Comment: It's like this:  1088491~20131128~00~11~108.000~17~17~22913~N~0~1.25~0.00~0.00~8.500~53.42~45.14~01

Comment: I am using EditPlus 3

Comment: So the **Tilda** character ( *~* ) separates the fields??

Comment: Yes and please bare with me, I am new to doing text files as part of my job.

Comment: I **will** bear with you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the **Data** tab, touch **From Text** in the **Get external data** group.

This will invoke the Import Wizard to allow you to pick the file............You can tell the Wizard to use the **tilde** as the separator.

Comment: One more question....the first column in Excel has 1.40023E+14 format - how do I make it exact the same number as in text file as 140022978037048?

Comment: The **Import Wizard** allows you to specify for each field, the desired format............either use the Wizard to specify text or re-format the column after the import is complete.

Comment: Thank you all over again for your assist in this! Fixed it and it's all good to go!